# HTTPS in ruby (connecting to https://docs.google.com/)

Tags: ruby

I am new in the world of Ruby so sorry if I say something stupid.

I am trying to automate downloading some videos shared by the members of a website using *https://docs.google.com/* and I am using Ruby to do it.

The link of each video has the following format :

```
  https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I noticed that the "Download Anyway" button redirects to the following link :

```
  https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=**FspT**&id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

So, I noticed that the **confirm** get parameter value changes. Once we click on that button we have our download link.

I tried to do it using the following code :

```
#GoogleDocs
def get_down_link_googledocs(url)

    #Getting the download webpage using https
    uri = URI(url)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
    data = http.get(uri.request_uri)
    body = data.body

    #Getting confirm value 
    confirm_regx = /confirm=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*/
    confirm = body.scan(confirm_regx)

    #if the link isn't correct 
    if confirm == nil
        return nil
    end

    #redirection link 
    confirm = String.new(confirm[0])
    url = url.gsub("https://docs.google.com", "")

    if url.include? "confirm=no_antivirus"
        request_uri = url.gsub("confirm=no_antivirus",confirm)
    else
        request_uri = url + "&" + confirm
    end

    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(request_uri)
    data = http.request(request)
    puts data.body  
end
```

But it puts the same webpage with an other confirm value.
What Am I missing here ?

Comment: not sure that i am following, though if the hassle of ssl bothers you, try out [`rest-client`](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client).

Comment: I usually default to [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday)